# Using this vs super in an extended class

Tags: java, inheritance

I have two Java classes:

```
public class foo{

    protected int foo_func(){
         //do stuff
    }
}
```

And also

```
public class bar extends foo{

    protected void bar_func(){
         x = this.foo_func();
    }
}
```

(It's worth noting that I didn't write these classes, I'm seeing them  in a project I'm working on)

Now, when I open up eclipse and look at the bar.java class I don't see any errors. Does the java compiler not see this as an issue? If not, what's the difference (in this case) between `this.foo_func()` and `super.foo_func()`?

Comment: You may need to review Inheritance rules one more time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If class `bar` doesn't override `foo_func`, there's no difference between `this.foo_func()` and `super.foo_func()`.

If, on the other hand, class `bar` would override `foo_func`, it can call `super.foo_func()` in order to perform the logic of the super class in addition of its own logic :

```
public class bar extends foo {

    protected void foo_func(){
         super.foo_func (); // calls the implementation of the super class
         ...
         ... // here you can add more logic specific to bar
    }
}
```

Comment: "If class bar doesn't override foo_func, there's no difference between this.foo_func() and super.foo_func()." Yes, there is: You cannot call super.foo_func() if it is not defined in the super class ;)

Comment: @1337 `foo_func()` being defined in the super class was one of the assumptions of the question.

Comment: Oh yeah you are right.. totally forgot that -  my failure - sorry man :)

Answer (score 0):

While `this.` and `super.` look very similar there is a big difference. While `super.` actually has an impact on the method invocation, in most cases, the `this.` qualifier has no influence on the code at all. Specifically, in your code `this.foo_func()` has exactly the same meaning as `foo_func()` (i.e. without the qualifier).

This means that in your code, `this.foo_func()` within the class `bar` invokes the method inherited from the class `foo` as there is no overriding method in `bar` but if the current `this` is an instance of a subclass of `bar`, let’s say `baz`, which overrides that method, the method of class `baz` is invoked.

In other words, the invocation `this.foo_func()` will still dynamically invoke the most specific method of the actual class of `this`, as said, just like without using `this.`

In contrast, `super.foo_func()` indeed requires a method `foo_func()` inherited from a super class and hence has an impact on the method dispatch as overriding methods in the current class and its subclasses are ignored. But even then, if you have a super class chain where more than one class defines that method, the most specific one will be invoked and you can’t chose a particular one.

Answer (score 0):

There isnt a difference. The child class `bar` is just simply making a call to the parent `foo's` method. `foo_func()` belongs to foo unless you decide to override it.